# Calling a C++ function with void* parameter in a C# app

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, void

I have a c++ function that look like this :

```
int Compression::DecompressPacket(const void* inData, int inLength, void* outData, int outLength)
{
    int headerLength = ComputeDataHeaderLength(inData);
    return DecompressDataContent(static_cast<const unsigned char*>(inData) + headerLength, inLength - headerLength, outData, outLength);
}
```

The fonction is inside a class which is inside a c++ library.

In the other hand, I need to call this fonction on my c# application. The fonction ask me to enter parameters of types : "void*, int, void*, int".

When I try to make a void* in an unsafe function,

```
unsafe private void lstbox_packets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   [...]
   byte[] value = byteValuePackets[lstbox_packets.SelectedIndices[0]];    
   void* pValue = &value;
   [...]
}
```

I get the error :

> Error 8   Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('byte[]')

I'm not very familiar with c++ and pointer but how i am suppose to pass a void* type in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't take the address of `value`, and also you have to use [`fixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) statement:

```
fixed (void* pValue = value)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Here's the link for the reference to fixed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The styling on the fixed keyword did not make it apparent it is also a link :)